# iOS App - "More" Area Doesn't extend over whole "Edited by LongUserName" Text

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Bit of a minor issue, but when I was trying to find out how to 'Favourite' a Question, I found an answer here that said you had to hit the three dots, or the the 'Edited by UserName'/Date area.  This is marked with a Red Box in the attached image.
But when I was testing this out I discovered that the long usernames pushes the "Edited..." text out of the hit area, the area Marked in the green box below

This is not too much of a problem but the text in the green box also responses to touches, it does what seems to be a standard touch down animation.

The combination of the unnecessary animation and the "hidden" feature - the three dots "more" together are a little confusing.

[image]

H/W iPhone 4

iOS 7.1.2

iOS-App SE version  1.0.1 05/13/20141.1.0

Comment: Yeah, that whole area is really hacked up because of the way iOS button image insets work.  I think the label view is completely covered by a view that redirects taps to the button, but the button doesn't register if they're too bar away...  Will look at doing something better.

Comment: Good luck! I've been in similar circumstances with iOS myself in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  The problem as I mentioned before was that we have a fixed width button because we want a wide hit area for the three dots but we want the three dots on the far left side.  I adjusted the tap forwarding view to adjust to the necessary size but for really, really long names the fixed sized button just wasn't cutting it.

So I got rid of the forwarding view and replaced it with a variable-sized button adjusting the left inset each time the view size changes, [taking advantage of IBDesignable and IBInspectable](https://gist.github.com/bnickel/6a0ff1019db1e3a66237) to avoid having to actually reference the button in code. :)